# Can't connect to spark web UI inside open shift container

Tags: apache-spark, openshift, spark-webui

I'm running my spark application in open shift container. The application runs for almost 2-4 hours. I do get the message of sparkUI started at http://hostname:4040. But when I click on it ,I'm getting webpage not found even though the application is still running .

Comment: Please clarify how your networking is setup. By default, ports would not be exposed outside the openshift cluster

Answer (score 1):

You should try with port forwarding: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/port_forwarding.html

```
oc port-forward -p mypod 4040:4040
```

then you can use the same URL, localhost or whatever is the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

While running your application, you can specify the port you want the web ui to run on.

For example,

spark2-shell --conf spark.ui.port=4040

Comment: The application is already started on port 4040 as i can see in the driver log , yet I'm getting web page not available when I'm clicking on the url

Comment: When you application is started, you should get a message:
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040.

You access the WebUI using http://10.0.2.15:4040

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to access the UI using the same URL and it's still inaccessible like i mentioned